# Python - How to export JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, python, json, jinja2

I want to export a JSON string in python into a JS variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = JSON.parse('{{ dataJSON }}');
    console.log(data)
</script>
```

If I print the content of `dataJSON` I get: `[{"offset":0,"total":1,"units":[{"village_id":37,"village_name":"Glim`

But in the JS I get this: `JSON.parse('[{&#34;offset&#34;:0,&#34;total&#34;:1,&#34;units&#34;:[{&#34;village_id&#34;:37`

I use jinja2 template engine: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#if

How can I fix that?

Comment: What template language are you using? Django, Jinja2, something else?

Comment: `jinja2` http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#if

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mark the data as safe:

```
var data = {{ dataJSON|safe }};
```

This prevents it from being HTML-escaped. There is no need to use `JSON.parse()` this way; JSON is a valid JavaScript subset (at least insofar that the Python `json` module produces a valid subset).

Take into account that this doesn't make it *JavaScript safe*. You may want to adjust your JSON serialisation. If you are using Flask, a `tojson` filter is provided that ensures you get JavaScript-safe valid JSON:

```
var data = {{ data|tojson|safe }};
```

If you are not using Flask, post-process the JSON:

```
dataJSON = (json.dumps(data)
    .replace(u'<', u'\\u003c')
    .replace(u'>', u'\\u003e')
    .replace(u'&', u'\\u0026')
    .replace(u"'", u'\\u0027'))
```

This is Python code to produce a `dataJSON` value that can be safely used in HTML (including attribute values) and in JavaScript. Credit here goes to the [Flask `json.htmlsafe_dumps()` function](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/cb25c42316690860fd928d9ec6fc997eea3f062b/flask/json.py#L161-L193).